# How do I invoke ACRA from a custom uncaughtException handler?

Tags: android, exception, acra, uncaught-exception

I need to restart the application from the beginning when a crash happens.
I am using this code to restart the application:

```
public class MyExceptionHandler implements
        java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private final Context myContext;
    public MyExceptionHandler(Context context) {
        myContext = context;
    }
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
        StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
        exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
        System.err.println(stackTrace);// You can use LogCat too
        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, Initialsetup.class);
        String s = stackTrace.toString();
        //you can use this String to know what caused the exception and in which Activity
        intent.putExtra("uncaughtException",
                "Exception is: " + stackTrace.toString());
        intent.putExtra("stacktrace", s);
        Log.d("bugFix4","Handling crash");
        myContext.startActivity(intent);
        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I also want to send error report as email by using ACRA.
Is there any way to invoke ACRA from custom UncaughtExceptionHandler ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(...)
```

Comment: when do i call this?

Comment: In the `uncaughtException` method. Before you kill the process.